# Entity Framework/WebApi unable to retrieve associated results

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to retrieve data as XML using Entity Framework and WebAPI.
All I get is an empty Child container, I have populated two records in OrderItem with OrderId=1 yet still nothing, see `<OrderItems/>` below:

```
<ArrayOfOrder xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApplication6.Models">
<Order>
<ID>1</ID>
<OrderItems/>
<Username>Test</Username>
</Order>
</ArrayOfOrder>
```

My Order model is as follows:

```
public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        this.OrderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }

}
```

My OrderItems model is as follows:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }

}
```

Controller code for GetOrders:

```
    // GET api/Order
    public IQueryable<Order> GetOrders()
    {
        return db.Orders;
    }
```

I am just trying to learn entity framework and WebApi, this part seems to be basic functionality and I can't find any solid reference to this at a basic level. Can anyone explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching I found the solution. Basically I needed to include the sub-dataset. This is done in the controller function:

```
public IQueryable<Order> GetOrders()
{
    return db.Orders.Include(p => p.OrderItems);
}
```

However this introduces the error:

> Object graph for type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[WebApplication7.Models.OrderItem,
>   WebApplication7, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if
>   reference tracking is disabled.

Which is fixed for XML by using Datacontracts
Updated `OrderItem` model:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
[DataContract]
public class OrderItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }

}
```

Note there is no [DataMember] annotation before Order
Now my result is as expected:

```
<ArrayOfOrder xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApplication7.Models">
<Order>
 <Id>1</Id>
 <OrderItems>
  <OrderItem>
   <Id>2</Id>
   <OrderId>1</OrderId>
   <Qty>231</Qty>
  </OrderItem>
  <OrderItem>
   <Id>4</Id>
   <OrderId>1</OrderId>
   <Qty>2314</Qty>
  </OrderItem>
 </OrderItems>
 <Username>first</Username>
</Order>
</ArrayOfOrder>
```

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/206942/is-moving-entity-framework-objects-over-a-webservice-really-the-best-way